# What are different ways to host c# code and trigger the hosted code?

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-triggers

I have created an MVC Application with three methods
1st method --> To Read data from SQL

2nd method --> To send picklist data to DevOps client (1st and 3rd methods will be called inside this method)

3rd method --> To create business rules in DevOps.

Now I want to host this application in Azure and want to trigger the second method once every day? I read we can do it by using web jobs. How can we create a Web Job for this requirement ,what we should write inside that web job script ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest WorkerServices for returning tasks.
The starting of the project is a bit annoying but overall it works quite nice.

I watched Tim Coreys [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzrTiz_NRKA) on how to get into them.